# Error trying to install Rling package in R

Tags: r

The following error occurs when I try to install the `Rling` package in R and RStudio:

```
install.packages("/Users/Jennifer/Documents/Carleton/9. F2018/LING4606/Rling_1.0.tar.gz",
                 repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

> Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) : 
>     embedded nul in string: '\037\x8b\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\006\xec\xbd\005X]\u02f2.\032$\x90@\xb0\xa0\xc1!\xc1\xdd\035B\b\020\xdc!\xb8L\xdc&\xee\022<\xb8\xbb\xbb\xbb\xbb3qwww\x87\x89<\xb2\xd6\xde\xfbl\xb9\xef\x9e\xfb\xdew\xf6\xba罻\xfa\xcb$\xdd\xd5\xdd\xd5\xd5]㯪\036\xa3瘲\xa6F\xe6\006t_\005\xe5\004dE\xa4\xe5'
>
> Warning message:
>   In install.packages("/Users/Jennifer/Documents/Carleton/9. 
>   F2018/LING4606/Rling_1.0.tar.gz",  :
>    installation of package ‘/Users/Jennifer/Documents/Carleton/9. 
>   F2018/LING4606/Rling_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`? (2) Do you have [`devtools`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=devtools) installed? If so, can you try `devtools::install_local("/Users/Jennifer/Documents/Carleton/9. F2018/LING4606/Rling_1.0.tar.gz")`? A [similar issue for a different package](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/155) suggested those steps as fixes; something that seemed to work for someone there was to install the `yaml` package, then re-trying the installation.

Comment: This is the output of sessionInfo()

Comment: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1

Comment: Just installed devtools with no issue so will try devtools::install_local("/Users/Jennifer/Documents/Carleton/9. F2018/LING4606/Rling_1.0.tar.gz") now

Comment: Jennifer, that type of output is rather difficult to read in a comment, even if it is complete (which I doubt in this case). Please edit your question and put the output there in a code-block.

Comment: @Jennifer I have tried several different ways to install this package and always run into the same error you do. I do not think this has anything to do with you doing anything wrong, I think there is a problem with the file provided at the [How to do Linguistics with R](https://benjamins.com/sites/z.195/content/package.html) website. You should try to contact the author/publisher to alert them of this issue.

Comment: @duckmayr Thank you. I appreciate your help. As someone who is new to this I am not sure even how to ask a question correctly or how to format them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the Rling package. I had this package installed before and had used it for years but recently updated R and RStudio and had to reinstall it. So, I am guessing that this is a bug that only affects newer versions or is related to the additional code that the author states needs to be added to install (repos = NULL, etc). Using devtools::install_local("/Users/Rling_1.0.tar.gz") worked without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this thread for anyone who gets the same issue in future (as I have today):

- There seems to be a newer version of the file on [Levshina's GitHub](https://github.com/levshina/Rling). Whatever I tried (and I tried *a lot*) I couldn't get anything to work with the file I downloaded from the website quoted in the "[How to do linguistics with R](https://benjamins.com/sites/z.195/content/package.html)" book. So definitely go to the GitHub first. There's also a link to download just the .RData file if the tar.gz file doesn't work.
- I also couldn't get install.packages command to work in the way quoted in both the book and the GitHub repository. I followed advice from this thread and another [more recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495190/error-trying-to-install-rling-package-in-r-2) and installed devtools:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
```

Then used the following:

```
devtools::install_local("/path/to/file/Rling_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Obviously, replace /path/to/file with the actual file path where your tar.gz file has been saved. I say this because for many of us this is our introduction to R and possibly coding in general, so I don't want to assume what people know or don't know already.

Hopefully that saves some other poor linguist a bit of time!