# Error trying to install Rling package in R #2

Tags: r, lib, install.packages

I tried to install a companion R package called Rling from this website https://benjamins.com/sites/z.195/content/package.html. In vain. There was an answer to the same question before [Error trying to install Rling package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349405/error-trying-to-install-rling-package-in-r). So I installed devtools with no problem. Then I used devtools::install_local to install Rling:

```
devtools::install_local(choose.files(), repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

But I received the following error message:

> devtools::install_local(choose.files(), repos = NULL, type = "source")
> Fehler in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
> Namensraum ‘processx’ 3.4.5 ist geladen, aber >= 3.5.0 wird benötigt

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Which R version are you using? The error you are seeing is becaus the `processx` library  on your system seems to be to old. You could try updating it...

Comment: R version 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`processx` is a package on CRAN:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/processx/index.html

It was updated in March 2021 to version 3.5.0 and in April to 3.5.1. The error message suggests to update as in

```
update.packages()
```

or just

```
install.packages("processx")
```

Comment: I did install.packages("processx") and it worked! Thanks a million!